# Exp:resso Store general questions

Tags: expressionengine, expresso-store

I've tried to contact Exp:resso Store support to ask some questions about their Store add-on for ExpressionEngine, but haven't heard anything back, and I really need to get started on my new online store project. I'm just wondering about the following things:

Is Paypal Website Payments Standard supported?

Can multiple images be added to products without extra EE add-ons (such as Channel Images)?

Can products belong to multiple categories?

Can discounts of the type: buy x of these, get z free be applied to carts? If not, how would I go about writing this? I'm guessing I could add products to a specific discount category, then add some logic to the cart to check if x amount of the products had been added, but is there an easier way?

I see that guest checkouts are possible, but if so how can customers securely view their order details without logging in according the Exp:resso Store site?

Thanks in advance if anyone is able to help!

Mike

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question would be better suited on the [ExpressionEngine Q&A site](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/). Also, it's best to only post one question per thread (so it's easy for people to submit multiple answers to each question). Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Paypal Website Payments Standard supported?

Paypal Express is supported, which has the same user experience as Paypal Standard but is more reliable.

> Can multiple images be added to products without extra EE add-ons (such as Channel Images)?

Store stays right out of how you manage images, this is up to you. You can use Channel Images, Matrix fields, regular EE file fields, etc.

> Can products belong to multiple categories?

Yes, again Store stays right out of how you manage your products. This is a standard EE feature.

> Can discounts of the type: buy x of these, get z free be applied to carts? If not, how would I go about writing this? I'm guessing I could add products to a specific discount category, then add some logic to the cart to check if x amount of the products had been added, but is there an easier way?

There is a [bulk discount extension](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-bulk-discount) on Devotee which claims to add this functionality (I have not personally tried it).

> I see that guest checkouts are possible, but if so how can customers securely view their order details without logging in according the Expresso Store site?

Store generates a secure random URL (called the "order hash") where order details can be displayed. You can email this link to your customers so that they can view it without being logged in.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrian, your help is much appreciated!